# Is GPU available in Azure Cloud Services Worker role?

Tags: python, azure, gpu, azure-cloud-services

Coming from **AWS**, I am completely new to **Azure** in general and to **Cloud Services** spesifically.

I want to write a python application that leverages GPU on Azure in a PaaS architecture (Platform as a Service). The application will hopefully be deployed somewhere central, and then a number of GPU enabled nodes will spin up and run the application until it is done before closing down again.

I want to know, what is the shortest way to accomplish this in Azure?

Is my assumption correct that I will need to use what is called [Cloud Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cloud-services/) with a worker role, or will I have to create my own infrastructure based on single VMs running in IaaS?

Comment: All SKUs are documented in detail on the Azure pricing page. gpu is only available on Virtual Machines (and yes, worker role instances are, under the hood, stateless Windows virtual machines, but there is no GPU-based sku for these, as it's a very different offering  than Virtual Machines). But as far as the rest of your question - not sure what you mean, about the shortest way to accomplish something.

Comment: VM Scale Sets can run on the N-series. Scale Sets are IaaS with autoscale (which you can hook to different triggers like CPU, memory, queues, etc) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-overview

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you created an application which need to do some general-purpose computing on GPU via Cuda or OpenCL. If so, you need to install GPGPU driver on Azure to support your Python application, so the Azure NC & NV Series VMs are suitable for this scenario like on AWS, as the figure below from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux/).

[image]

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: So i need a vm, no PaaS then. Right?

Comment: @LennartRolland Sure, just my advice. If you want to do something like Machine Learning, I also suggest you can try Azure Machine Learning or Azure Cognitive Service.